# VBA To colour cell diagonally with 2 colours based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to diagonally colour cells with 2 colours should the cell value equal specific text. Can anyone assist with adjusting the code below to do this?

```
Sub ChangeColor()
    Dim rCell As Range
    With Sheet1
    For Each rCell In .Range("C4:Q38")
        If rCell.Value = "A/R" Then
            rCell.Interior.Gradient.ColourStops.Add Color = RGB(242, 220, 219)
            rCell.Interior.Gradient.ColourStops.Add Color = RGB(235, 241, 222)
            .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
            .Gradient.Degree = 45
            .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear

        ElseIf rCell.Value = "C/I" Then
            rCell.Interior.Gradient.ColourStops.Add Color = RGB(218, 238, 243)
            rCell.Interior.Gradient.ColourStops.Add Color = RGB(253, 233, 217)
            .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
            .Gradient.Degree = 45
            .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I've made the following revisions to the Code but am now getting a `For without Next` error but cant seem to determine where it belongs?

```
Sub ChangeColuor()
    Dim rCell As Range
    With Sheet1
    For Each rCell In .Range("C4:Q38")
        If rCell.Value = "A/R" Then
        With rCell.Interior
            .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
            .Gradient.Degree = 45
            .Gradient.ColourStops.Clear
            rCell.Interior.Gradient.ColourStops.Add Color = RGB(242, 220, 219)
            rCell.Interior.Gradient.ColourStops.Add Color = RGB(235, 241, 222)
        
        If rCell.Value = "C/I" Then
        With rCell.Interior
            rCell.Interior.Gradient.ColourStops.Add Color = RGB(218, 238, 243)
            rCell.Interior.Gradient.ColourStops.Add Color = RGB(253, 233, 217)
            .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
            .Gradient.Degree = 45
            .Gradient.ColourStops.Clear
        End With
        End If

    End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient` is referring to `With Sheet1`? Seems like you need an inner `With rCell.Interior`... `End With`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen - can you assist with where the code can be updated? I pieced this code together based on what i found online in a few different places.

Comment: I would follow the approach in the linked question. It seems like you're doing things in reverse. First set the `.Pattern`, then clear the `ColorStops`, then add the new ones, then modify their properties. Use the macro recorder to help, if needed.

Comment: Looks like it's `ColorStops` too - yay American English.

Comment: @BigBen Gave your recommendation a shot but I'm getting a compile error (Method or data member not found) for the .Pattern line of code. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a `With rCell.Interior` that the `.Pattern` is referring to?

Comment: Thanks @BigBen - I added the `With`statement after `Then` which ran the code past the .Pattern line after but I'm now getting an (Else without If) error?

Comment: Missing an `End With` probably

Comment: Now I'm getting  the For without Next error but cant figure out where it goes?

Comment: @BigBen I updated the question with the new code. Now I'm getting a `For without Next` error. Any suggestions on where it should be added? I cant see to place it properly.

Comment: Hi @BigBen Just wondering if you have any suggestions for how I can get this code to work?